# Redireccionar y Ocultar Paneles al mismo tiempo en C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo dos paginas pagina 1 y pagina 2, cuando el usuario da clic en el botón pagina 2 pretendo me redirecciona a pagina. Con esto no tengo ningún problema, sin embargo en pagina 1 tengo 3 paneles y quisiera ocultar 1 panel en el momento de la redireccion, es posible?

Lo estoy redireccionando con el response.redirect

```
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_sec_despacho))
        {
            _sec_despacho = "0";
        }
            num_sec_gestion = gestioncomercial.insertarNuevaGestion(_compania, _sec_orden_compra, _sec_despacho, dllAccionNueva.SelectedValue.ToString(), dllEstadoNuevo.SelectedValue.ToString(), txtFecSeguimientoNuevaGestion.Text, txtObservacionesNuevaGestion.Text);
            Response.Redirect("~/GestionCompras/SGC0001.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: cuand dices "panel" a que control de asp.net haces referencia?

Comment: en el codigo que muestras se ve la redirecion, pero la idea es ocultar el panel cuando redireccionas pero si ingresas navegando normalmente se debe visualizar?

Comment: no en el page_load de pagina 1 el panel que quiero mostrar está oculto, y el panel que quiero no se muestre en pagina 1 esta visible, actualmente no hago referencia al panel en el response porque no se como hacerlo

Comment: no entendi, el panel que tienes en la pagina1 esta oculto, pero entonces se visualiza, no queda claro. Que tiene que ver el reponse?

Comment: Voy de nuevo en panel 1 tengo 3 paneles al cargar la pagina solo muestro 1 panel que contiene un grid, al seleccionar el registro en el gri me lleva a panel 2 y 3 y en ese momento oculto el panel 1. En estos 2 paneles que igual contienen grids al seleccionar me redirecciona a pagina. Entonces quisiera que al realizar la gestion que corresponde en pagina 2 me redireccione a pagina 1, pero ocultando el panel 1, solo quisiera mostrar en ese momento panel 2 y 3.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias enviar un flag desde la `pagina2` para conocer que el ingreso proviene de una vuelta entonces proceder a ocultar el primer panel

la redireccion la harias usando

```
Response.Redirect("~/GestionCompras/SGC0001.aspx?vuelta=true");
```

Nota: ese flag lo invente, puede definir algun otro

Entonces en la pagina donde estan los paneles, en el Page_Load puedes validar

```
public void Page_Load(...){

  bool vuelta = false;
  if(Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("vuelta")){
      Boolean.TryParse(Response.QueryString["vuelta"], out vuelta);
  }

   if(vuelta){
      Panel1.Visible = false;
   }
}
```

si ingresa sin la key se comporta normalmente, pero si vuelve con el valor en la url podras saberlo y ocultar el panel

Otra alternativa sino queres algo en la url es que uses el objeto `Session`, pero como lo planteaste relacionado al redirect imagine seria algo con la url

Comment: Gracias Leandro, Solo una más, lo coloque justo como me lo compartiste sin embargo tengo ese error en la compilación                                                         Error 49 'System.Web.HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for 'QueryString' and no extension method 'QueryString' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpResponse' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  sabras de casuliada a que se debe este error, la palabra String la S la tengo en mayuscula

Answer (score -1):

Estaría bueno que redactes un poco mejor la pregunta pero entiendo al punto que quieres llegar.

Eso lo puedes hacer con un `ViewBag`, un viewbag es un objeto dinamico, y se lo pasas a la vista o puedes hacer un `div` al panel (si es que utilizas Bootstrap) le agregas la propiedad `hidden` o con css `visibility`, o puedes agregar una condición por fuera del `row` que te oculte ese panel.

**Ejemplo:**

CÓDIGO:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_sec_despacho))
        {
            _sec_despacho = "0";
        }


       ViewBag.OcultarPanel = true;


       num_sec_gestion = gestioncomercial.insertarNuevaGestion(_compania, _sec_orden_compra, _sec_despacho, dllAccionNueva.SelectedValue.ToString(), dllEstadoNuevo.SelectedValue.ToString(), txtFecSeguimientoNuevaGestion.Text, txtObservacionesNuevaGestion.Text);
            Response.Redirect("~/GestionCompras/SGC0001.aspx");
        }
```

VISTA:

```
@if(ViewBag.OcultarPanel){
<panel>...</panel>
}
```

Comment: la pregunta se plantea usando asp.net no asp.net mvc